# How to call a py file compiled in an exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I made an HWID Spoofer and using --add-data, I compiled multiple py files into the required exe.
I made sure to import the other py files to my main hwid spoofer py file.
Now my question is, How do I call these multiple py files when all these py files are compiled into the exe.

Sorry, I know my english is garbage, this is the best I could put it in.

I tried os.system, but wont work because this command searches for the py file in dir...

I tried the exec command, but it didn't work...

Here is the command I used:
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/icon.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/generate_fingerprint.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/hardware_fingerprint.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/identity_data.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/log_helper.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/random_utils.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/registry_helper.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/system_fingerprint.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/system_utils.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/telemetry_fingerprint.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/winmac.py;."  "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/tog6_spuf.py"`

Comment: What do you mean "What is the source code to run the python file from the compiled exe?"

Comment: @ShivamJha I have made an HWID Spoofer and have compiled everything to one exe.
Now this py file i want to call is mac_changer.py. What python code can I use to call this py file to the exe? I'm sorry, I'm not too fluent at english, this is the best I could do

Comment: Please post the command you used to generate the `.exe`.

Comment: @DanielF I have edited the description, it now has the command I tried...

Comment: Where are you calling `os.system()` from? Can you run the `.exe` by double clicking on it?

Comment: @DanielF here is an example
`tydf = random.choice(USERNAMES)
 stupiddude = getpass.getuser()
 subprocess.call("powershell.exe Rename-LocalUser -Name " + stupiddude + " -NewName ", tydf)`

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand but if these modules are imported and used by tog6_spuf.py then no need to use --add-data for them.

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I just understood.
Thanks for the help dude!

Comment: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/icon.ico"  "C:/Users/shyaa/Desktop/TOG6 HWID Spoofer/tog6_spuf.py" should do the trick

Comment: @EricMathieu But after that I have to leave all the pyfiles outside right?
I'm trying to find a way to avoid that

Comment: No this is the whole purpose of PyInstaller: the pyfiles are embedded in the exe. Just give it a try !

Comment: @EricMathieu Tried it, probably I made a mistake!
Lets say I imported the py files.
Now with what command can I call those files when needed?

Comment: can you clarify what you want to achieve ? Do your scripts define functions to be called or are they just  a suite of statement ?

Comment: @EricMathieu I'm sorry my english is bad, so I didn't understand what you mean by define functions to be called, but I was wondering if this would work...
`import get_mac.py
print("Getting New MAC To Spoof")
get_mac()`

Comment: @TOG6: I am not a python pro but this not likely to work even directly from the interpreter. I put a example in an answer

Comment: You should consider using a [spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) to include all of your non Python files. It will make your command line shorter. Pyinstaller will normally do a good job finding .py files, so you shouldn't need to `--add ` them in your command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proper way in python to get this work.
This is get mac

```
def get_mac():
    print("get_mac I am")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_mac()
```

And this the main

```
import get_mac
print("Getting New MAC To Spoof")
get_mac.get_mac()
```

Comment: Dude @Eric Mathieu, You Are A Genius...
This worked for me!
Thanks a TONNNN!
Go get a job in python xd

Comment: @TOG6. Great. Would you mind "accepting" my answer please.

Comment: Sorry, Accepting? I don't understand, New to Stackoverflow :-(